# CASE statement to create another window within a partition in BQ based on lag/lead row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to do a sql query that will create groups within an order by based on whether the next row is .01 seconds later.

For a project I am working on I have dummy data with times a cellphone was pinged during different apps. We have to calculate various metrics and if the phone isn’t pinged for a few seconds that should be a different group.

[image]

```
SELECT APP_ID, 
Session_id, 
Phone_id, 
Time_pinged, 
LAG(Time_pinged,1) 
OVER(PARTITION BY App_id, Session_id, Phone_id order by Time_pinged) as Lag_time,
LEAD(Time_pinged,1)
OVER(PARTITION BY App_id, Session_id, Phone_id order by Time_pinged) as Lead_time
FROM Mydataset.app_data
```

I am trying to add another “grouping” to this query to take into account when the session loses connections for a few milliseconds so even though the last 2 rows are in the same session_id, it lost connection for a millisecond so there should be 2 unique groups within this session.

I’m trying to figure out how to do a case statement where I could create another grouping within the Session_id (for a given app/user) based on this formula: 
lead(time_pinged,1)-time_pinged != .01

My initial thought was to create start/end “windows” to say:
If: `time_pinged - lag(time_pinged,1) != .01` -> start frame
And case 
`lead(time_pinged,1) - time_pinged != .01` -> end frame. Now I don’t think I need both of these cases because if I know the end frames I know the start frames but im not sure.

Thanks so much.

Comment: @mikhailberlyant I just accepted, I am sorry. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT App_id, Session_id, Phone_id, Time_pinged, 
  COUNTIF(new_group) OVER(PARTITION BY App_id, Session_id, Phone_id ORDER BY Time_Pinged) sub_session
FROM (
  SELECT App_id, Session_id, Phone_id, Time_pinged, 
    CAST(Time_pinged - LAG(Time_pinged) OVER(PARTITION BY App_id, Session_id, Phone_id ORDER BY Time_Pinged) as NUMERIC) > 0.01 new_group
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

If to run above against sample data in your question  - result is

```
Row App_id  Session_id  Phone_id    Time_pinged sub_session  
1   AppA    g12_ab      89002       0.01        0    
2   AppA    g12_ab      89002       0.02        0    
3   AppA    g12_ab      89002       0.03        0    
4   AppA    g12_ab      89002       0.04        0    
5   AppA    g12_ab      89002       0.08        1    
6   AppA    g12_ab      89002       0.09        1
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a cumulative sum.  That is, use `lag()` to define where groups start and then assign a group number based on a cumulative sum.

```
SELECT ad.*,
       COUNTIF( lag_time < time_pinged - 0.015 ) OVER (PARTITOIN BY App_id, Session_id, Phone_id) as grp 
FROM (SELECT ad.*
             LAG(Time_pinged, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY App_id, Session_id, Phone_id ORDER BY Time_pinged) as Lag_time,
      FROM Mydataset.app_data ad
     ) ad;
```

Comment: When I try this I get Star expansion expression references column Session_id which is neither grouped nor aggregated at, the error in bigquery seems it's coming from the ad.* in line 1

Comment: @WIT . . . It needs the `OVER` clause.